# ForEach Controller is not getting Triggered in Jmeter when using List from JSR223 Preprocessor

Tags: jmeter

I need to read a folder and store the file names in a list.Then,I have a For each controller on which the filename list should iterate(i.e) I have a sampler inside For each and I have to pass different file path in that HTTP request in Files upload Section.

i have successfully read files from folder and stored that in a list and passed that list as input in For Each Controller.

but my ForEach controller is not even getting hit(not listed in View Results tree) and i can't able to see any info regarding that in my console.

reading File from folder and store in array

```
import java.io.File;
File file = new File("D:\\testdata\\trunk\\version2\\Jmeter\\loadscript\\Files\\txt\\test")
  String[] arr = file.list()
  def varList =[] 
  for(String e : arr){
     varList.add(e)
  }
  vars.put("filelist",varList)
```

ForEachController:
[image]

When I am using debug PostProcessor,the values inside list is displayed correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) picks up JMeter Variables in form of:

```
filelist_1
filelist_2
filelist_3
etc.
```

So you need to slightly amend your code to look like:

```
File file = new File("D:\\testdata\\trunk\\version2\\Jmeter\\loadscript\\Files\\txt\\test")
String[] arr = file.list()
arr.eachWithIndex { f, index ->
    vars.put("filelist_" + (index + 1), f)
}
```

Also you may find [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin easier to use, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)